# Switch between two routers (one used as acess point)

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, switch

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ZmX.jpg)

This is the setup I have. My problem is there is no Internet on desktop. It can't get IP from router. Even if I manually configure it, still says unidentified network. DHCP is disabled on second router. When I remove second router from switch, everything is fine on desktop. I don't know what my problem really is so couldn't really search for it. Is it possible to work like this ?

Main router TD-W8960N,
Access point router ZXHN H108N V2.5

Comment: Check to ensure the AP router ports are not configured for specific/special usage or something like that I suppose. Ensure you plug the switch into the AP LAN ports only and don't use the AP WAN ports at all. Again, confirm you do not have the ports configured with a special config and when that specially configured port is connected to the switch, it brings down the network or whatever you see there. Are you accessing the AP via WiFi when you have the problem from the laptop? Does the laptop have the problem when connected to the AP via LAN side Ethernet?

Comment: If you have this problem only when connected via WiFi to the AP and not the LAN side port, then you might need to ensure the WiFi configuration that gives IP addresses is configured to not overlap with the main router DHCP and it needs to be configured to use default gateway as the IP address of the main router. If you are connecting via WiFi, then I suspect the WiFi is using DHCP or else you connect to WiFi from AP and set your own IP statically? Ensure when connected the default gateway IP configurations via cmd `ipconfig /all` shows the IP for the DGW as the IP address of the main router.

Comment: Also see what the DNS settings are set to for whatever DHCP IP address you get when you have the problem and ensure those DNS settings are accessible, need adjusted, etc. to be routable when configured with the setup that is not working. This is not rocket science and should be something simple being overlooked so check the TCP/IP configurations and record those and compare what they are when they DO and DO NOT work both. Compare and see if you notice any differences that may give a clue. Check the other things I've mentioned as well.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the Access Point router back to factory specifications and allow it to restart.

1. Hook up a LAN port on your Access point router to a LAN port on the other (Main) router.
2. Log into the Access Point router, give it a Static IP address on the Main Router. This is your network subnet.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the Access point.

Now the Access Point is an extension of your network. Reset any Wireless Settings and all should work fine now.

Comment: I think I did those but I am unsure. I gave 192.168.1.175 to access point router, DHCP is disabled. I can login to access point router  and main router from laptop. 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.175

Also It was 192.168.1.250 before, out of range of DHCP, could that be a problem ?

Comment: You need to look at the DHCP range of the Main Router and then set the Access Point outside of that range.  Usually (not always)  .1 to .10 are not int the DHCP range.

Comment: I did it, Now it gets IP from DHCP but when I try to browse anything, I got an error page saying  "No Dsl Connection". This error page is from access point router (192.168.1.175), but I want my desktop to connect main router.

Comment: Check the IP ranges very carefully on both routers. The above setup is something I have used successfully for years and have running here. Perhaps reset both router to factory specifications and try setup again.

Comment: Does IP ranges at access point router have impact? I thought it is not that important because DHCP is disabled anyway. Should I make it same with main router ?

Comment: Check the IP ranges very carefully on both routers. The above setup is something I have used successfully for years and have running here. Perhaps reset both router to factory specifications and try setup again.

Comment: DHCP for access point and router, should they be the same ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: For the Access Point, disable DHCP and then anything connected to it will get an IP from the main network. You do not want two DHCP servers running. That will confuse things.

Comment: Yes I did that so what you mean by IP range on second access point router ?

Comment: You should get the same kind of IP (with Internet) on your access point (192.168.1. x )

Comment: @PimpJuiceITI already did those nothing changed. Both are 192.168.1.x

Comment: In order to be sure the setup steps work (you have made some changes), reset both routers to factory specifications, set up the main router first. Be sure it works in all respect and note it IP address and where DHCP occurs (what range it has). Then set up the Access Point following my 3 steps above precisely.

Comment: Also if you remain stuck, check each router independently for proper operation